# StringToWordVector stuck in setInputFormat

Tags: java, string, weka

I have a problem while using the weka StringToWordVector. How can I create a word matrix from a list of strings?

In my code, I create instances from strings. As soon as I want to identify the setInputFormat(), the code runs into some kind loop with no process activity in the background. A result is never reached, it just continues running without progress and no error.

Here my code example that causes my problems:

```
    ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();

    stringList.add("test1");
    stringList.add("test2");

    Attribute attributeContent= new Attribute("content", (ArrayList<String>) null);

    attributesList.add(attributeContent);

    Instances data = new Instances("Strings", attributesList, stringList .size());

    for (String s: stringList) {
        DenseInstance instance = new DenseInstance(1);
        instance.setValue(attributesList.get(0), s);
        data.add(instance);
    }

    StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();
    Instances newData = null;
    try {
        filter.setInputFormat(data);
        newData = Filter.useFilter(data, filter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the code works fine... I had a problem with my dependecies in Java. Because of the play framework I used, Java did not perform an auto-load of an alternative for the netlib library. This library picks a linear regression optimised for an OS, I had to set the following flag in Intellij and it works:
[image]